# How to connect to Mysql through Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, rcp

I am try to connect to mysql database through a RCP project. I downloaded the Mysql Jconnect file. Extracted to a folder. Set the classpath variable as mentioned in the document. Still I am not able to connect to Mysql. 
I am getting this error

```
SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
SQLState: 08001
VendorError: 0
```

I then tried add mysql-connect jar file as external jar file in the project, still no luck. Tried adding it as a user library, nothing happened.

Finally I created a "plugin project from existing jar file" option and used the mysql-connect as the jar file. Then in my RCP project I added this plugin as dependancy plugin, yet same result.

I am absolutely sure of the code, the error is in the classpath. How do I resolve it.

My configs are :

OS: Ubuntu 10.04

Mysql version: 5.2.1

Eclipse : 3.5

I tried putting the file in /usr/bin directory, that didn't work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg03367.html) does mention:

> After rechecking everything I found that mysql configuration on the second computer was not to listen for network connections, after fixing that, (almost) all started to work fine
>
> P.S. but anyways, **reading that there is no suitable driver it is hard to guess, that the driver is found but failed to connect :)**

So maybe this is not a path or classpath issue, but a mysql configuration issue.

---

Actually the OP confirms in the comment that it was a classpath issue:

> This thing finally worked. I copied the `mysql-connect` jar file into the project folder and **added it to the runtime classpath of `plugin.xml` file**.
> The important thing here was **I had to just enter the file name and not the absolute path**.

Comment: I don't think so. MYsql is configs are ok.

Comment: So figured it out, the problem was infact with the class path. This thing finally worked. I copied the mysql-connect jar file into the project folder and added it to the runtime classpath of plugin.xml file. The important thing here was I had to just enter the file name and not the absolute path 
:)

Comment: @Chaitannya: great! I have included your specific step in my answer.

Comment: Hi Chaitannya/VonC: I have tried your method and it still does not work. Can you please post a step by step document somehow so everyone can understand the exact steps? Thank you