# how to connect eclipse rcp application with mysql database

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I have created database and Application for my Eclipse RCP project.
now how to connect this project with MYSQL database.
if i am trying to connect it is giving error "class not found".

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a JPA provider with support for OSGi bundlers as http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/.

OR

1. Create a plugin from JDBC driver  (plugin from exists jar) and set it as dependent of your applicantion. With this you can to acess the driver class (check OSGi bundle dependency for more details)

Answer (score 0):

The same question has been asked by a user :-
Follow the link
Connecting RCP to database

[How to connect to Mysql through Eclipse RCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293321/how-to-connect-to-mysql-through-eclipse-rcp)